# Map is rendering gray using react native

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps

I'm doing a project in React Native and I want to put a map using the Google Maps API. But I'm having a problem that nothing is showing (it's gray) as the image. I've looked at several posts on Stackoverflow and I couldn't solve my problem.

[image: app's print]

My code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import MapView, {PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from 'react-native-maps';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native'; // remove PROVIDER_GOOGLE import if not using Google Maps

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});

export default () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <MapView
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
      style={styles.map}
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 37.78825,
        longitude: -122.4324,
        latitudeDelta: 0.015,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
      }}
    />
  </View>
);
```

In my local.properties file (in the root of the android) I put my credential (for testing purposes, it's unrestricted)

```
MAPS_API_KEY=AIza...
```

My build.gradle file (in android root)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        playServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "11.8.0"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:1.3.0"
    }
}
```

My app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [MAPS_API_KEY: "$System.env.MAPS_API_KEY"]
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<manifest ...>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

  <application ...>
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
                  android:required="false" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I created app/src/main/res/values/google_maps_api.xml

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">AIza...</string>
</resources>
```

I tried to add this line on app/build.gradle

```
plugins {
   id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
}
```

and I got this error:

[image: error]

But my main problem is not showing the map (or showing in gray), as the first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the plugin part to the following on app/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
         classpath "com.google:plugin:0.6.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.google.secrets_gradle_plugin"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem entering in this link:
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/maps-android-backend.googleapis.com

And then, you need to enable the MAPS SDK FOR ANDROID:
Also, you have to make sure to add the google api key.

[image]